# Why does an AWS Glue Resource Policy fail with a "Principal does not exist" error when in fact the Principal (a role) is in existence

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, identity-management

In Terraform I am trying to create a Glue Resource Policy which allows a specific IAM Role to use the Glue resources.

Relevant TF snippets as below:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "process_banking_data_sfn" {
  name = "process_banking_data_sfn"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "states.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_glue_catalog_access" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "glue:GetTable",
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:glue:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_target_account_number}:*"]
    principals {
      identifiers = [
        aws_iam_role.process_banking_data_sfn.arn
      ]
      type = "AWS"
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_glue_resource_policy" "glue_resource_policy" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_glue_catalog_access.json
}
```

On `terraform apply`, the following error occurs:

```
rror: error putting policy request: InvalidInputException: One of the principals in the policy does not exist.
│
│   with module.banking_analyses.aws_glue_resource_policy.glue_resource_policy,
│   on ../../modules/banking_analyses/glue_data_catalog.tf line 134, in resource "aws_glue_resource_policy" "glue_resource_policy
```

When `terraform apply` is run a second time, the Glue Resource Policy is created just fine.

Things I have already tried:

- Replacing the aws_iam_policy_document with an inline (<<EOF) policy
- Adding a `depends_on [aws_iam_role.process_banking_data_sfn]` to the aws_iam_policy_document
- Adding a delay / sleep of 10 seconds before creating the Glue Resource Policy

These fail. Interestingly if I stop trying to reference the IAM Role as the Principal and instead use the ARN of the account root, the Terraform applied first time without complaint (however this is totally useless for my actual needs; I was just isolating a proof that it is the IAM Role that is the source of the error message).

If I refresh the AWS UI during the failing apply process, I can see that the role "process_banking_data_sfn" is created very early in the `apply` process, long before the Glue Resource Policy creation fails.

Any experienced advice would be *GREATLY* appreciated.

Edit:

On reflection I think it’s significant that to the terraform process it appears that we know the ARN of the Role already. It’s clearly been created. Plus I checked the logs and the unique ID of the role remains constant across both apply runs (the failing one and the successful one) so it seems to me the error is generated by AWS when at the back end the process validates the existence of the Principal. This may sound obvious but I think the clue is in the fact that we (terraform) can see the role before AWS can. Therefore I’m wondering if it’s something to do with the non-regional nature of roles and that the new Role isn’t propagating quickly enough to the part of the stack which deals with validating the Glue Resource policy. I’m wondering if perhaps I should use a separate Providet in us-east-1 to do this Glue Resource creation, so it’s “closer” to IAM.

Comment: The issue is only with TF? What if you try to create the resource policy manually in console for glue with the role?

Comment: The first thing that terraform is going to do before anything else is to run data and fetch all that is there in it. Using data source is an assertion by the author that a particular external source exists and we are calling it for our use. In your case since the arn it expects to get is not yet created it complains of it being missing.

one workaround that i found is to construct the arn instead of referencing it directly : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#basic-example

Comment: @AbhishekMalik That is not accurate, I'm afraid. As per TF docs "Terraform defers reading data resources [when] at least one of the given arguments is a managed resource attribute or other value that Terraform cannot predict until the apply step." - https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources#data-resource-behavior

To prove this, in my TF log I can see that the Resource Policy has correctly resolved the Principal: `"Principal\": {\n        \"AWS\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456:role/process_banking_data_sfn\"\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}")`

Please correct or remove your answer, thank you.